# Getting Unable to find column with logical name error when I refer to composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've see this question in several posts here. But found non of them helped me to fix it. And unable to track on why this exception is happening.

Here are my entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "iiot_machine")
public class IIOTMachineModel {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "machine_id")
   private String machineId;

   @Column(name = "machine_name")
   private String machineName;

   @Column(name = "machine_description")
   private String machineDescription;

   @Column(name="created_on", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
   private LocalDateTime createdOn;

   <-- Setters and Getters -->
}
```

Second Entity with Composite Entity with Composite Key as follow

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "iiot_shift")
public class IIOTShiftModel implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "shift_id")
   private String shiftId;

   @Id
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="machine_id", referencedColumnName = "machine_id")
   private IIOTMachineModel machine;

   @JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING, pattern = "HH:mm:ss")
   @Column(name = "start_time")
   private LocalTime startTime;

   @JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING, pattern = "HH:mm:ss")
   @Column(name = "end_time")
   private LocalTime endTime;
    
   @Column(name= "created_on", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
   private LocalDateTime createdOn;

   <-- Setters and Getters -->
}
```

So far, with these two above entities, when I run the application, everything works fine. But when I add below entity which has One-to-May Relation ship with shift, I'm getting an error. Entity is defined below

```
@Entity
@Table(name="iiot_product")
public class IIOTProductModel implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 7807669404047523909L;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "product_id", length = 100)
   private String productId;

   @Id
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="machine_id", referencedColumnName = "machine_id")
   private IIOTMachineModel machine;

   @Column(name = "line_id")
   private String lineId;

   private String variant;

   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumns({
       @JoinColumn(name="shift_id", referencedColumnName="shift_id"),
       @JoinColumn(name="machine_id", referencedColumnName="machine_id")
   })
   private IIOTShiftModel shift;
   private String operatorName;

   <-- Setters and Getters -->
}
```

Here with this Entity, particularly when I'm mapping shift with two keys, I'm getting this error. Please let me know if I'm missing something in here.

Full Stack Trace as follows

```
2020-07-16 15:45:20.436  WARN 21496 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method 
failed on bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': 
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: 
machine_id in iiot_shift
2020-07-16 15:45:20.436  INFO 21496 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 
'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-07-16 15:45:20.437  INFO 21496 --- [  restartedMain] 
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-64 - Shutdown 
initiated...
2020-07-16 15:45:20.450  INFO 21496 --- [  restartedMain] 
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-64 - Shutdown 
completed.
2020-07-16 15:45:20.576  INFO 21496 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

Comment: Could you please provide a **full** stack trace of your error. This is noticeably help us to help you.

Comment: @SternK Added the full stack trace as you have suggested

Comment: @sternk, Sorry, I feel like I am on stepping too often on issues you are trying to help with as well

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai  no problem! We all are here to learn something from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need two primary key classes

```
   public class IIOTShiftModelPK  implements Serializable {
     private String machine;

     private String shiftId;

     .....getters and setters
}
```

```
   public class IIOTProductModelPK  implements Serializable {
     private String productId;
     private String machine;

     ..getters and setters
   }
```

- Use the primary key classes

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="iiot_product")
    @IdClass(IIOTProductModelPK.class)
    public class IIOTProductModel implements Serializable {
```

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "iiot_shift")
    @IdClass(IIOTShiftModelPK.class)
    public class IIOTShiftModel implements Serializable {
```

- Updated product model as primary key is used part of join to another relationship

```
    @Column(name = "shift_id")
    private String shiftId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name="shift_id", referencedColumnName="shift_id",
                        insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name="machine_id", referencedColumnName="machine_id", 
                        insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private IIOTShiftModel shift;

    public IIOTProductModel(String productId, IIOTMachineModel machine, 
                            String lineId, String variant, 
                            IIOTShiftModel shift, 
                            String operatorName) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.machine = machine;
        this.lineId = lineId;
        this.variant = variant;
        this.shift = shift;
        this.operatorName = operatorName;
        if (Objects.nonNull(shift))
            this.shiftId = shift.getShiftId();
    }

    public void setShift(IIOTShiftModel shift) {
        this.shift = shift;
        this.shiftId = shift.getShiftId();
    }
```

- See the Github repo with solution. https://github.com/kavi-kanap/stackoverflow-62934039

Comment: Seems it's working but failing while adding foreign key constraints. This is the exception I'm getting.
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table iiot_product add constraint FK2u1hp5vo8jarrk5jag998vsih foreign key (machine_id, shift_id) references iiot_shift (machine_id, shift_id)" via JDBC Statement

Comment: It doesn't look like hibernate issue as it worked for me. Try dropping all the tables and recreate

Comment: Wow!!! Like you said, I dropped all the tables and recreated. It's working. What could have happen over there?

Comment: Also for every entity which has a composite primary key, should I create an ID Class?

Comment: yes. You either to use `IdClass ` or `EmbbededId`. In both cases, you need a class for that. https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-composite-primary-keys